# Passing an id attribute to a dynamically generated content in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button `Create` that dynamically generates a div content. In this content, I have a `Save` button that performs an ajax call to save the data inputted within this dynamically generated div content. Inside the same dynamically content, I have a `Delete` button that perform a delete of this div content together with the data saved from the ajax call. The issue is that I am obtaining the id from the db as a return from the ajax the `Saved` content. Up to this, all is good. And consequently I can use this id to perform the delete operation.

My issue is how to do I pass this `id` to the attribute of the delete button within the dynamically generated content so that when I click the delete button the corresponding div content data is deleted from the db.

```
var idToDelete = 0;

    $('.js-create-btn').click(function () {        

        var divContent = `<div class="serv">
        <div class="serv__menu-title">
            <input type="text" id="menu-title" class="orga-title js-menu-title" placeholder="Enter a value">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button save-btn js-menu mdl-button--icon">
                <i class="icon-add"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button delete-menu- js-menu-title mdl-button--icon" id-to-delete="">
                <i class="icon-delete"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Now I target the `Save` button within the dynamically added content to save the value as :

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-save', function () {
var portion = $(this).closest('.serv__menu');
var name = portion.find('input[type="text"]').val();

 var datatoInsert = {
            name: name
        };

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveDetails", "MainMenu")',
            data:
                {
                    valDetails: JSON.stringify(datatoInsert)
                },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Value saved');
                idToDelete = data;
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Error');
            }
            });
```

My question is how can I pass this `idToDelete` to the `<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button delete-menu- js-menu-title mdl-button--icon" id-to-delete=""><i class="icon-delete"></i></button>` to the attribute of `id-to-delete` as this is dynamically generated ? Please help.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `id-to-delete="${idToDelete}"` when creating the `divContent` value? Then you can just use `.attr('id-to-delete')` to get the value later

Comment: @Phil : Nope. it is giving me `0`.